# error when start Subversion Server in UberSVN

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I'm using uberSVN on Ubuntu server. Now, I can't checkout, commit source from Subversion Server ( domain.com:9880, port subversion)

I tried to start httpd by command line as:

```
sudo /opt/ubersvn/bin/httpdserverctl start
```

, but I get error:

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
httpd (pid 895) already running
```

I tried run this command as follow:

```
cd /opt/ubersvn/bin
 sudo ./ubersvncontrol start
```

then get errors:

```
Starting SysV Tomcat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/ubersvn/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/ubersvn/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/ubersvn/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/ubersvn/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/ubersvn/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /opt/ubersvn/data/run/tomcat.pid
Existing PID file found during start.
Tomcat appears to still be running with PID 943. Start aborted.
```

In the Ubersvn website GUI, I tried start Ubersvn server but get error :

[image]

How to start Subversion Server ?

Comment: What error message are you getting when you attempt to check out or commit?

Comment: hi  Shane Madden, I can't connect ubersvn port 9080, then i can't checkout or commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the answer for my problem. You just need delete the file `/opt/ubersvn/data/run/tomcat.pid` and remove all file in log folder of Ubersvn `/opt/ubersvn/data/logs/`.

Then you could restart the this server.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is only the warning. Change the `ServerName` directive in the Apache configuration file to something like this `ServerName :80` to make it go away.

The second line means that...the Apache is already running. How about this:

```
cd /opt/ubersvn/bin
./ubersvncontrol start
```

Comment: hi quanta, i've updated my question with command that you need. Please check it. :) thank

Comment: Did you see that _Tomcat appears to still be running with PID 943. Start aborted._?

Comment: I see that, but how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status and start, stop or restart Apache and uberSVN from the 'Status' tab of uberSVN.

What does it say the status is currently?

Comment: Hi Mand Beckett, I just updated my question above about the state `status tab`, you can see it.